# Draw triangle at bottom or top of line

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

In below code I'm attempting to draw a triangle at bottom of line (to represent a arrow) :

Code :

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 200)
        .attr("height", 200);

//Draw the line
var line = svgContainer.append("line")
        .attr("x1", 5)
        .attr("y1", 5)
        .attr("x2", 5)
        .attr("y2", 50)
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("stroke", "black");

line.append("svg:path") 
        .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol.type("triangle-up"))
        .style("fill", "black");
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/3420/

But receive error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

How can the triangle be drawn at top or bottom of line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to make the arrowhead so manually. SVG has a way to put a marker at the end and/or beginning of a path, and it rotates it for you to match the path's angle. Check out any tutorial about SVG arrowheads, like [this one](http://www.svgbasics.com/markers.html).

Still, if you want to do it the way you started:

`d3.svg.symbol.type("triangle-up")` should become `d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up")`

and

Instead of `line.append("svg:path")`, which puts a path inside a line element (hence invalid), do `svgContainer.append("svg:path")` to make the path a sibling of the line.